# In Azure Data Factory I have Created self hosted IR. But from few days it's status is showing as Running(Limited). Can I know the reason Why?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, ssis-2012

In Azure Data Factory I have Created self-hosted IR. But from few days its status is showing as Running (Limited). I have Three nodes in it. Can I know the reason why its status is showing as Running (Limited).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Nodes may be unable to communicate with each other, resulting in this error.

Go to particular node and get into **Integration runtime >> Diagnostic >> view logs**

[image]

now you will be redirected to event viewer and filter the error logs.

[image]

If there's an `System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException` and `System.Net.Sockets.SocketException`  these errors contain in above error logs.

run the following command in a Command Prompt window:

```
telnet 10.2.4.10 8060
```

As [Microsoft official Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/self-hosted-integration-runtime-troubleshoot-guide?tabs=data-factory#error-message-self-hosted-integration-runtime-nodelogical-self-hosted-ir-is-in-inactive-running-limited-state) states,

> **To resolve this, make sure that all the nodes in your domain are using the same IP address, and you will need to add the IP address to the host files for all the hosted virtual machines.**